# Page numbering in MS Word: How do you insert both a page number for the volume (page X of XX) and for the chapter?

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers

I'm not finding the field code that will help with this. Two sets of instructions that both need to be followed.

1. Each page in each Volume shall be numbered sequentially by the Offeror. So, we need page numbering that reflects the sequential page we're on.
2. In addition to the volume numbering required, within each Work Sample, each page will be sequentially numbered 1-10. For example, Work Sample 5, page 4, would be annotated as WS5-4.

So. Set section breaks for each WS/chapter/section, I get that, and start each section's page at 1. Inserting a page number for each of these functions will only work for one of these functions; you can't change one without changing the other, i.e. if you tell the page numbering to start at 1 for one field, the other will also automatically do that. I'm going to have to find a different field code that will do either full volume numbering, or section numbering. Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The usual suggestion for this is

- put each Work Sample in a separate Word Section
- Put a bookmark at the same location in each Section (e.g. always at the beginning or always at the end)
- Use `{ PAGE }` for the "Continuous number sequence" and use a calculation using `{ PAGE }` and `{ PAGEREF "the bookmark name" }` for the Work Sample sequence

But before going any further it's probably worth mentioning that because other things rely on page numbering and other types of numbering (e.g. Tables of Content, Indexes, sequences where you need `Page x Of y` both for the document and per Work Sample, do you have odd/even section breaks, and so on), it's worth making sure that whatever method you end up using actually does everything it needs to, especially in the context of a bid where even a minor misunderstanding of the requirement could cost you.

There is also a potential problem with using Word Sections because sometimes you cannot avoid putting them where you don't really want them - e.g. if you have to switch from portrait to landscape or from a single-column to snaking columns layout. There's another approach that relies on using automatic heading numbering instead that might work better.

For the Section numbering approach, let's say you put a bookmark at the beginning of every Work Sample. Let's say you call them s1, s2 and so on. Then you can get the page number within section 1 using the nested field code

```
{ ={ PAGE}+1-{ PAGEREF s1 } }
```

where all the { } have to be the special field code brace pairs that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Desktop Word.

i.e. you could get the WS5-4 format code using

```
WS{ SECTION }-{ ={ PAGE}+1-{ PAGEREF s1 } }
```

As it stands, that would require a different header or footer for each Section. But you can use the s1, s2 naming convention to fix that, like this:

```
WS{ SECTION }-{ ={ PAGE}+1-{ PAGEREF "s{ SECTION }" } }
```

And in fact once you've done that, you can see that by using a { SET } field to insert the bookmark, you can use the same coding at the beginning of every Section body:

{ SET "s{ SECTION }" "x" }

(I only put an "x" in there to make sure the SET field succeeds.)

You also need to update field results to get the pagination right, and in a long document that may take some time.

However, I don't think you actually need to use Sections at all, because the following fields should accomplish the same thing:

At the beginning of every Work Sample, put the fields

```
{ SEQ s \h }{ SEQ p \r{ ={ PAGE }-1 } \h }
```

and in your header footer, for the Work Sample numbering, use

```
WS{ SEQ s \c }-{ ={ PAGE }-{ SEQ p \c } }
```

( `s` and `p` are just Sequence identifiers, `\r` resets the sequence to the given number, `{ ={ PAGE }-1 }` in this case, `\h` hides the result and `\c` inserts the current value of the sequence (which is correct even though the header at the beginning of the Work Sample comes visually before the corresponding field coding).

That said, I know that the first approach and its variations have more documentation scattered around the web, which suggests they have been used more in practice and that you're more likely to get support if necessary.

Comment: Wow, thank you for a phenomenal and detailed answer to this. Off to make it work. Thanks so much!